# Pygame mouse click | Toggle play pause in music playing s

Tags: python, pygame, logic

I am trying to make a music playing system. I have made a class called Circle which defines the button and their attributes which has a method called click() that detects whether the particular area in the screen is clicked or not.

```
 def click(self):
    """
        In general, point x and y must satisfy (x - center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2 <= radius^2
    """
    current_mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    value_of_equation_at_current_mouse_position = (current_mouse_position[0]-self.x)**2+(current_mouse_position[1]-self.y)**2
    if (value_of_equation_at_current_mouse_position <= self.radius**2):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

I want to toggle the play and pause buttons when I click. 
My logic:

```
 if btn_play.click():
    if togglePlayaPause == 1:
        if paused:
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

        played = 1
        togglePlayaPause = togglePlayaPause ^ 1
        pygame.time.wait(250)
        print("clicked")
        a = 0
        b = 1024
        paused = False


if togglePlayaPause == 0:
    pygame.time.wait(550)

    if btn_pause.click():
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        print("paused")

        paused = True
        newSong = 0
        played = 0
        togglePlayaPause = togglePlayaPause ^ 1
        pygame.time.wait(250)

if togglePlayaPause == 1:
    btn_play.draw()
else:
    btn_pause.draw()
```

Since both the play and pause buttons lies on the same co-ordinates the method clik() returns true for both and both the if statements executes as a result of which the music pauses after some time it is being played. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `togglePlayaPause` is 1, then  `btn_play`  has to be evaluated else if `togglePlayaPause` is 0, then `btn_pause` has to be evaluated.

Use  a [`if` `elif` `else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) statement to do so:

```py
if togglePlayaPause == 0:
    if btn_play.click():
        if paused:
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
        # [...]

elif togglePlayaPause == 1:
    pygame.time.wait(550)

    if btn_pause.click():
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        # [...]
```

or

```py
if togglePlayaPause == 0:

    # [...]

else: # togglePlayaPause is either 0 or 1

    # [...]
```

Comment: Thank you, just didn't thought that way :D